# link pipeline-build to board-item

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that runs regularly every 8 hours. It's task is to checkout a bunch of repositories, compile multiple projects and run some tests. The pipelines yaml-file is stored in `Repo1`:

```
resources:
 repositories:
   - repository: Repo1
     type: git
     name: Repo1
     ref: main
   - repository: Repo2
     type: git
     name: Repo2
     ref: main
   - repository: Repo3
     type: git
     name: Repo3

stages:
  - stage: 'CompileAndTest'
    jobs:
      - job: 'x86'
        timeoutInMinutes: 240
        
        steps:
        - checkout: Repo1
          lfs: true
        - checkout: Repo2
          lfs: true
        - checkout: Repo3
          lfs: true                     
          
trigger: none
schedules:
  - cron: "0 6,14,22 * * 1-5"
    displayName: daily every 8 hours
    branches:
      include:
      - main
    always: true
```

In order to link work items to commits I enabled the appropriate option within my pipeline:

[image: link work-items to commits]

Now I get a few work-items that are related to the build within the build itself:
[image: related items].

As an aside in the image there are 19 repos. For the sake of simplicity I just mention 3 here.

The commit associated with that item was done on `Repo2`, so on a different repo than the one where the pipeline is stored. However when I go to the the mentioned item, it doesn't show the build within the `Integrated in build`-field. **Is that because the commit was done on another repo than the pipeline?**

Comment: do you mean to Integrated in build field? do you see the build in the "links" tab?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, I ment the integrated in build-field. No, I cannot see the build within the links-tab. There are only the commits associated to the item.